# mysql get price range between column

Tags: mysql, sum, between

**tbl_Rate:**

```
|  FROM  |  Stop1  |  Stop2  |  Stop3  |   TO   | Stop1_rate | Stop2_rate | Stop3_rate | full_fare
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Alba  |  aaa    |  bbb    |  ccc    | alfa   |    50.00   |    60.00   |    50.00   |    200.00   |
|  City  |  vvv    |  www    |  xxx    | city2  |    45.00   |    50.00   |    60.00   |    195.00   |
```

This table is travelling fare rates.
When user search from where and going to rate should come as result.

When user travels from Alba and going to alfa, the result should be 200.00 **(full journey fare)**
I know how to search from where to where going like below. but i don't know how to get rate in SQL.

```
<form><input type='text' name='from'><input type='text' name='goto'><submit></form>
```

SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE from='$from' *or* stop1='$from' *or* stop2='$from' *or* stop3='$from' **and** *to*='$goto' *or* stop3='$goto' *or* stop2='$goto' *or* stop1='$goto'
```

Is there other good method like **FIND_IN_SET**

and I want to get rates too..

If user travel and search between Alba to ccc
1st stop rate charge 50+ stop2 for add 60+ stop3 for add 50= total amount 160.00

If user travel city to vvv (from to Stop1 travelling)
total should be 45.00  (45 stop1 rate charge)

If user travel city to vvv (from to Stop2)
total should be 95.00  (45 stop1 rate charge+ 50 stop2 rate = total 95.00)

Comment: Are there only ever 3 stops and what purpose does the to column serve

Comment: Please formulate the rule, not "for example".

Comment: Your database model is inconsistent. Going from "Alba" to "bbb" has the same cost than going from "aaa" to "bbb": `110`  (= 50 + 60). I'll vote to close since the question is not well formulated.

Comment: @P.Salmon maximum 5 stops, this trip booking, who can search from where to where going. then stopping points and rates. is there any other way like with two tables or if possible 1 table better.